# update_user_meta not updating

Tags: actions, user-meta

I'm trying to force password change upon first user login, which overall is not working, but so far I find a problem update_user_meta() is not updating at all, this is my code:

```
function track_last_login($login)
{
    global $user_ID;
    $user = get_userdatabylogin($login);
    $Nlogins = (int)get_user_meta($user->ID, 'Nlogins', true);

    if (!$Nlogins) $Nlogins=1;
    else $Nlogins++;

    update_user_meta($user->ID, 'Nlogins', $Nlogins);

    if ($Nlogins==1)
    {
        add_action('admin_notices', 'showAdminMessagePwd');
        header("Location: http://example.com/wp-admin/profile.php");
    }
    else
        remove_action('admin_notices', 'showAdminMessagePwd');

}
add_action('wp_login','track_last_login');

//(showAdminMessagePwd is a function already defined)
```

According to my log messages, the value of Nlogins is 1 before update_user_meta but it stays in 0 in database an every new login is like the first.

What am I doing wrong?

Another question is: Why does *add_action('admin_notices', 'showAdminMessagePwd')* only works when called from outside a function (directly in *functions.php*) and not when called inside this function.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like it didn't work when the meta_key has a 0 value in DB, but works when it doesn't exist or has a value>=1, so this part is solved. So, my other question was: **Why does *add_action('admin_notices', 'showAdminMessagePwd')* only works when called from outside a function (directly in functions.php) and not when called inside this function?**

Comment: Edit the question with the new question

Answer (score 1):

In response to the extended question, i.e. ***Another question is[...]:***

It is worth noting that Wordpress' plugin API does not persist between requests - that is to say, any functions associated with actions through Wordpress' `add_action()` are only associated for the duration of the script's execution. Each subsequent request served by Wordpress must once again bind functions with their proper actions (again, only for the duration of the request/script execution).

That in mind, you are binding the function `showAdminMessagePwd()` to the action `admin_notices` immediately before you execute a header-redirect, which ***[should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001564/how-long-after-sending-a-headerlocation-command-will-the-php-script-pro)*** briefly prompt the client browser to terminate the request and start a new one at the indicated location. I may be misinterpreting the situation, but it seems reasonable that `showAdminMessagePwd()` is no longer bound to the action `admin_notices` when the script at **http://example.com/wp-admin/profile.php** executes as the `add_action()` call that binds it was executed in the context of an entirely separate request.

Binding the action *within* your **functions.php** file and outside of a function works fine because all of the code in a theme's functions file is executed whenever the theme gets loaded (for the intents and purpose of this question, virtually *always*). Binding the action in a function will work flawlessly so long as the function is executed, and your function bound before the `admin_notices` action is executed.

One solution might be to attach the logic that determines whether or not to display to an action that executes on every request rather than `wp_login`, which only executes after a user has authenticated themselves. Such an implementation might look something along the lines of

```
function track_last_login( $login ) {
    $user = get_user_by( 'login', $login );
    $nLogins = (int) get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'Nlogins', true );

    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'Nlogins', $nLogins + 1 );

    if( $nLogins === 1 )
        header("Location: http://example.com/wp-admin/profile.php");
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'track_last_login' );

function admin_password_notice() {
    //If the user isn't logged in, or they are viewing pages outside of the dashboard, ignore them.
    if( !is_user_logged_in() || !is_admin() )
        return;

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $nLogins = (int) get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'Nlogins', true );

    if( $nLogins === 1 )
        add_action('admin_notices', 'showAdminMessagePwd');
}
add_action( 'after_theme_setup', 'admin_password_notice' );
```

Note that *no* calls to `remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'showAdminMessagePwd' )` are necessary as, if `$nLogins` does not equal `1`, the function is never bound to the action (no calls to `add_action( 'admin_notices', 'showAdminMessagePwd' )` have been made), and thus no binding exists to be removed.

Also note that [the function `get_userdatabylogin()` has been deprecated](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdatabylogin) as of Wordpress 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how is the flow going on exactly, but I had an issue with a very similar problem where I'm dumping the value above update_user_meta and it works below (even in the DB) and it doesn't work at all anywhere without the var_dump. I've reported it [on Trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20690) but no response so far.